# How to enable mod_rewrite module for docker official httpd image?

Tags: apache, docker, mod-rewrite, build

I am running a LAMP stack in docker with the help from docker-compose, and for the webserver I am using the official image from https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd. The httpd container is created by a Dockerfile:

```
ARG APACHE_VERSION
FROM httpd:$APACHE_VERSION
RUN apt-get update;\apt-get upgrade;\a2enmod rewrite
COPY demo.apache.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf
RUN echo "Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf" \
    >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

I am trying to enable mod_rewrite with the `\a2enmod rewrite` command but I get the following error during build:

```
/bin/sh: 1: a2enmod: not found
ERROR: Service 'apache' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update;\apt-get upgrade;\a2enmod rewrite' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

a2enmod is failing – from my reading it's only available in a debian system and the httpd base image doesn't have it.

How can I enable mod_rewrite module for this docker official httpd image during build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. I had to enable the module in the apache .conf file by adding the line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: But then how did you add this line to the config file?

Comment: @MusaHaidari the docs suggest obtaining the default configuration for the container then `COPY`ing it to your image
https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/httpd#configuration

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `a2enmod` to enable certain module for Docker official httpd image. All you have to do is explicitly add the module to apache.conf file. So in my case, I need to enable mode_rewrite, here's my example Dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd:2.4-alpine

RUN echo "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

COPY ./html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

Comment: It's already in the default config, just commented out. Docs suggest obtaining the default config and `COPY`ing that to your image: https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/httpd#configuration